# how to remove the root on a simulate android studio device

Tags: testing, automation, appium-android

I am trying coding a test automation for a mobile application but this application has a restriction about the root devices so when I try running the application on the device, the application take me out.... is there a way to start the mobile on andriod studio as unroot device?